# French internationalisation, override babel default spacing

Tags: formatting, punctuation, babel

I'm writing my thesis paper in French. In the document I use the name of the `ISO27001:2005` norm name, and by babel conventions this is rewritten as `ISO27001 :2005` with a extra space before the semicolon.

The behaviour is expected in all the document but not when I write this name.

What is the best way to tell the engine to ignore default formatting rules and write the : without extra space?

Answer (score 11):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand\ISO{ISO27001:2005}
\begin{document}
ISO27001:2005

ISO27001\string:2005

{\NoAutoSpacing ISO27001:2005} %needs frenchb.ldf version 2.5f

{\shorthandoff{:}ISO27001:2005} 

\ISO
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Ulrike `NoAutoSpacing` works only with `frenchb.ldf` version 2.5f and not with the version of TL2011

Comment: @Altermundus: Yes you are right. I had completly forgotten that I had a new version laying around im my test folder.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\shorthandoff{:}` before the code and `\shorthandon{:}` after

Comment: Ulrike shows in this code the use of TeX's group. With a group, it's possible to avoid the use of `\shorthandon`

Answer (score 3):

The user guide for `babel` provides the following recommendation for locally suppressing the extra space that's inserted (when the `frenchb` option has been set) before `:`, `;`, `!`, and `?`: Insert the instruction `\string` immediately before the respective characters.

The following MWE shows how this works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\begin{document}
ISO27001:2005

ISO27001\string:2005
\end{document}
```