# How to suppress the space before the colon, in French language?

Tags: babel, french

I would like to suppress the space before the colon, when using `[french]babel`. I only want to change this locally (that is not everywhere in the document, but just at some place).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}
Il est 20:20.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How about 20{:}20? Not sure.

Comment: No, it prints the same.

Comment: For a similar problem when using `polyglossia` instead of `babel` see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187864/remove-space-before-punctuation

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the usual way to denote time in French; here's a workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\edef\hc{\string:} % \hc prints a normal colon

\begin{document}
Il est 20\hc20.
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, use `datetime`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}

\newcommand\heure[2]{\formattime{#1}{#2}{00}}

\begin{document}
Il est \heure{20}{20}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the usual way to denote time in French is 20h20.

Comment: @giordano I also suspect “20:20” is not common.

Comment: It is true, but in some contexts, `20:20` is better. For instance, if you say : "The digital alarm clock was displaying 20:20".

Answer (score 30):

Your problem is with the Babel shorthand for `:`. To disable this shorthand use `\shorthandoff{:}` **inside** your `\begin{document}`. It will not work when loaded in the preamble.

To re-enable the shorthand, use `\shorthandon{:}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}
\shorthandoff{:}
Il est 20:20.

\shorthandon{:}
Il est 20:20.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good suggestion, but doesn't work with ``XeLaTeX`` ... the log file suggests using ``\NoAutoSpacing`` instead.

Comment: This works sooo fine on bibliography, it's gem !!! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 14):

As suggested by [PatrickT](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155015/how-to-suppress-the-space-before-the-colon-in-french-language#comment744212_155060) and mentioned in [French internationalisation, override babel default spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36509/french-internationalisation-override-babel-default-spacing), `\NoAutoSpacing` is the easiest solution in modern (post-2011) TeX distributions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}
Il est {\NoAutoSpacing 20:20}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please add a MWE?

Comment: edit: added a MWE

Comment: See also the documentation of Babel French http://daniel.flipo.free.fr/frenchb/frenchb-doc.pdf   This command is necessary for example for natbib bibliography style plainnat (and \shorthandoff does not work in that case).

Comment: Thanks for writing this up, because I had forgotten about my comment of 8 years ago. This issue came up again with the package `datetime`. To get the correct spacing, I've had to type `\NoAutoSpacing\currenttime` to get the correct spacing when compiling with `XeLaTex`. I wish I could upvote again!