# Remove space before punctuation

Tags: luatex, polyglossia

I need to remove locally spaces arround (especially before) punctuation signs. This spaces are added by french polyglossia.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}

\newcommand{\nospace}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

\begin{document}
\nospace{a:b}
\end{document}
```

[image: space to remove]

Thanks for help.

Comment: I think there is a reason for that: Are you in math mode or trying to write some program code? Or are you locally changing to another language?

Comment: I'm trying to write some program code (like '=SUM(B2:C3)' for spreadsheet program).

Comment: Then you might want to take a look at package `listings`.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\begin{document}
a:b
\begin{lstlisting}
a:b
= SUM(B2:C3)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
`

Comment: It's just for some commands inside text, not for a full programm code.

Comment: `Text \lstinline{= SUM(B2:C3)} more text
`

Comment: But it doesn't work in a tabular environment. I think there is a more 'simple' solution for that (without listings package).

Comment: @MB78 why should `\lstinline` not work in a tabular? (Or perhaps you mean something different with “it doesn't work”?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is another solution, without extra package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nospace}[1]{\nofrench@punctuation\texttt{#1}\french@punctuation}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\nospace{a:b}
\end{document}
```

Thanks all.

Comment: Perhaps better: `\newcommand{\nospace}[1]{{\nofrench@punctuation\texttt{#1}}}`

Answer (score 11):

Probably Polyglossia should offer the possibility of disabling the automatic spacing feature for French in certain contexts such as monospaced text. However, here's how you can do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\setmainlanguage{french}

\xapptocmd\ttfamily{\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=0 }{}{}

\newcommand{\nospace}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

\begin{document}
\nospace{a:b}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A possibly better workaround is to use `\nofrench@punctuation` as you found out:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xapptocmd\ttfamily{\nofrench@punctuation}{}{}
\makeatother

\setmainlanguage{french}

\newcommand{\nospace}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

\begin{document}
\nospace{a:b}
\end{document}
```

This indeed takes into account the possible usage of LuaLaTeX instead of XeLaTeX.

Comment: Thanks, I will try. For polyglossia, the \nonfrenchspacing command is available but it doesn't seem to do what I want.

Comment: `\nonfrenchspacing` is for getting extended space *after* punctuation in the British/American style.

Comment: Ok. So I haven't seen any command for space _before_ punctuation in the polyglossia documentation. (Nothing like the frenchb babel \NoAutoSpaceBeforeFDP)

Comment: Perhaps the polyglossia solution is something like that `\newcommand{\nospace}[1]{\nofrench@punctuation\texttt{#1}\french@punctuation}`.

Comment: @MB78 My workaround will work for every text that uses `\ttfamily`, including `\texttt`

Comment: Yes, so the \nospace command seems to be useless, \texttt{a:b} should be enough. For my use, 
I do not want to generalize removing spaces in a whole family font. Thanks to you.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way seems me to use \string:

```
a\string:b
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX and thanks for answering and participating here! Unfortunately, this does not work for me. Please extend your answer in order to show a full example which works. And maybe explain, what is happening here and where `\string` comes from. As it stands now, it is a bit short and would be more suited as comment to the OP. It could get closed so I would advice you to improve the answer a bit. Thanks.

Comment: The `\string:` trick works with `pdflatex` and `babel`, not with XeLaTeX (either with `babel` or `polyglossia`).